# jQuery slideToggle and positioning bug

Tags: jquery, html

The URL below works fine. Uncomment the jQuery to see the problem.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Iikuv

When you uncomment the jQuery you see the slide effect is not "smooth" and its because im switching back and forth between absolute and relative positioning.

toggle comment this jQuery

```
/*
  //Uncomment for the bug
  if(navIcon.hasClass('open')){
    navIcon.css('position', 'relative');
  }else{
    navIcon.css('position', 'absolute');
  }
*/
```

any solutions?

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: I press on the icon, everything disappears

Answer (score 0):

I dont see what exactly you want to do, so please describe in detail what you want to achieve. One problem is, when you set the position to absolute, div.container looses its height. You can solve this in setting:

```
.container {
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

for example.